# How to pass value from views.py to display on sendmail

Tags: python, django

I'm new in sendmail and I want to know if it is possible to pass a context value from views to Forms.py in django sendmail. In the image attached, the context value "getlogincode" is not displaying after I receive an email using sendmail.

[image]

forms.py:

```
class MyCustomLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        html_content = render_to_string('getlogincode_sendmail.html')
        send_mail(subject="Reliance Assurance Worth", message=html_content, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, recipient_list=[self.user.email], html_message=html_content)
                
        # You must return the original result.
        return super(MyCustomLoginForm, self).login(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py:

```
def GetLoginCodeView(request):
    #Get User LOGIN CODE
    user = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    for code in user:
        getlogincode = code.login_code
        #print(getlogincode)

    context = {
        'getlogincode': getlogincode,
    }
    return render(request, 'getlogincode_sendmail.html', context)
```

Template" getlogincode_sendmail.html

```
<p style="padding-bottom: 16px">Please use the login code below to complete your request.</p>
<p style="padding-bottom: 16px"><strong style="font-size: 150%;">{{ getlogincode }}</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[render_to_string()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) doesn't actually use the GetLoginCodeView view, only the template you pass it.  So it doesn't have the info on how derive the login code.

You can fix this by passing the request along with the template:

But first off, you probably don't want the login() method to be on the form itself.  If you are submitting the form to a view, you could do this:

````````
def login_page(request):
    form = forms.LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #send the email```````
            html_content = render_to_string('getlogincode_sendmail.html', request = request)
````````

Now your template can refer to the user's profile.login_code directly (assuming a one-to-one between user and profile)

```
<p style="padding-bottom: 16px">Please use the login code below to complete your request.</p>
<p style="padding-bottom: 16px"><strong style="font-size: 150%;">{{ request.user.profile.login_code}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: Hello, your first method do not pass the value on the template, your second method display a server error 500.

Comment: I just noticed your login() method is on the form (I was expecting a view), but you haven't shown how that method gets called. You'll either need to pass the request object as an argument to the login() function or do it in the view ( which already has the request object). I've added some code for the latter

Comment: I'm using django allauth for my login

Comment: This worked correct rendering sendmail in views.py. Thanks!